Viability of wells in a desert world; would it realistically work?
So I have this concept of this corporation capitalizing on the near lack of water available, save for oases here and there, on the surface by renting out (for quite high prices might I add) electric well pumps to people.
Sounds like a great business plan, but I was thinking if there would even be a watertable here. See, this story takes place in not just a desert, but a desert punk world. It, as far as I have planned it, never had biomes (besides small oases) rich in water, nor does it rain much more than every few years in most places, if that.
So because of this, would wells be viable in a desert world like this? If not I can always handwave, but it would be neat to put some realism in it. I mean there are oases, so maybe it could work, but maybe it would only work in the vicinity of one.
Just for clarification, I am not looking to get answers/feedback on if rentable well pumps are a good business strategy as a concept outside the fact of if it would be possible for them to work in the first place.

A well is a hole in the ground. Cannot be electric. Do you mean electric pumps?

Yes, I mean pumps. I guess I linked the 2 in my mind. Also, why the downvote over this? @AlexP

Life-bearing single biome worlds are implausible altogether.  It doesn't stop some great worldbuilding being done with them - as Dune proves - but they are not science-based.  Note that the TV tropes page you linked has a direct link to https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SingleBiomePlanet

There is a quite extensive aquifer under the Sahara. There is also one under both Saudi Arabia and Iran: yes, it extends under the Persian Gulf and yes, it's freshwater. It feeds the famous artesian spring in Bahrein, among others.

Living off a fossil aquifer works until it stops working. Consider the fate of the Garamantes.

the whole planet cannot be desert and still have humans living on it, the air will kill them.  so you decide how much realism you want,  it is up to you if wells work.

Selling anything for a high price requires that the potential customers have a viable economy apart from what you are selling. In this case, that would not exist. How would your customers get the money to buy the water?

I'm begging you, on my hands and knees, to use the Sandbox. I'll let this question slide, but whether or not something is viable is irrelevant to worldbuilding. Lakes exist in desert areas. So, do you want wells on your desert world? Ask us how to rationalize them. Don't hand us your complete idea and then ask if it's good. If the worldbuilding is complete, the question is off-topic. Review questions are Opinion-Based by definition. Sandbox. Please use the Sandbox.

Depends on how realistic or 'hard' one wants their world. Let us use scifi. Soft scifi, sure, that is correct, but hard scifi askers need questions even more IRL centric, and based off tags, it is not breaking the rules. Sometimes, askers just want a bit of reality in their worlds @JBH

@ConanHighwoods This has nothing to do with the scope of the answers or any tag that exists on this site. It has to do with how you're asking questions - which is badly. PLEASE use the Sandbox (or go to meta and explain to the community why you're refusing to do it).

My correct point still stands.@JBH

You probably need some expert knowledge on desert grounds/structures. I can provide this much:
There are different reasons why an area has become a desert. Constituting factors are geological features like global position, elevation, surrounding mountain ranges, river flows (or their absence) etc. - which also define the presence of water, winds and temperatures and finally rainfall, vegetation and water preservation/vaporization on the ground.
Deserts appear in varying ground materials also connected to the geological features, and for example deforestation by human intervention which leads to extreme influences by the sun/heat. The results can be more like sand (Sahara), salt (Salt Lakes/New Mexico) or stones/pebbles (Atacama, Gobi) or solid rock (Cyrenaica/Libya, Nabatea/Petra/Jordan, Australia, Sierra Nevada and other high ground mountain ranges). Several ground structures of those may be present in desert regions closely together.
The availability of water is dependent on factors like: Are there (underground) river flows (Mojave), is it purely dependent on rain (Atacama) or is there a groundwater layer accessible within feasible efforts (Kalahari being probably an example of low chance). There can be a kind of river bed constellation which allows floods ("flash floods") to bring a lot of water to the desert for a certain period of time but this happens only so often, like every 10-20 years or so (Wadis, Nubian, Nile in Sudan (formerly also in Egypt) more regularly, yearly floods).
Oases can form because there is some water saving layer in the ground in varying depths, e.g. clay or rock, which prevents water from vaporizing and seeping away. Also most oases have some kind of human-made irrigation system to it, needing tools like water wheels to bring water to the surface and distribute it. Sometimes there is a real overground spring that sustains an oasis. Growing trees/vegetation which provide shadow also helps preventing vaporization processes of the valuable liquid.
So, if the conditions come together in a way that water is present but accessible only in deeper layers which are harder to get to, the corporation might expand on also offering drilling equipment for a "(un-)fair" price tag along with a rent for providing the water pumps (and the fuel for them).
The thing is: If water is available within several meters of depth and the ground allows it, humans can just dig a hole with simple tools to reach it, thus creating a well. To scoop water from it they could use the classical "bucket on a string" method or some kind of tripod with a boom and some counter-weight to easily descent a leather skin "water bag" to get water to the surface. -- This would not be a good place for the company to make a fortune (Except they resort to more violence and punish creating of wells without "their permission"; will also result in more insurrection against that company).
The deeper and more complex it is to reach the water, the better the chances are for the company. Penetrating solid rock (granite) or reaching high depths with simple tools won't be possible. Drilling a hole with a diameter of about 20cm to create a well will not allow using a bucket, but makes using pumps and pipes or hoses mandatory. Maybe the water is also needed in great amounts (for supporting an irrigated oasis for example) and a pumping around the clock is necessary to bring decent amounts of water to the surface. -- Here the company will get stupid rich -- if there are people in demand of water and able to afford the high prices (and are not able or willing to build a pump themselves instead of renting them).

"The low rainfall impacts the ground material"?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If there are natural oases then there is a water table that is coming to the surface in places. Where there is an existing water table you can dig down to it and use pumps to extract water, at least for a while. In a world covered in deserts there is space between sand grains and within the (often made of far coarser particles that have more pore space) basement regolith for water storage deep below the visible sandy surface. Without general surface exposure the water isn't going to be subject to much evaporation and will accumulate over time if not artificially extracted. Natural oases are going to be found where this deep global aquifer is intercepted by the topographic surface, artificial wells can be created anywhere. The deeper the water table is in a given area the harder wells are to dig and maintain and the more people will have to rely on the company and it's hardware. In low lying basins people can dig simple scrape wells, i.e. being able to dig down to the water table with their bare hands, but on higher ground drilling and then lining of wells is probably required.
Having thought about this scenario for a minute I see there being two sub-classes on this planet, the poor and the "watered poor". The simplify slightly on a desert world the hottest place at any given latitude is at the lowest elevation. The basins close to aquifer depth are therefore the harshest places on the planet to live. The poor who cannot afford access to powered pumps will have to live at low altitudes where they can dig their own shallow wells. Those who live at higher elevations will have it softer but will have as little, or even less, disposable income, this is because they rely on powered pumps, that they must lease on usurious terms, for their survival.
